# Magento 2 and intact IQ Software

Tags: magento2.3

My client is using IQ software. They want to integrate the necessary stock levels to the website so it pulls the data so there is no chance of selling an item that is not in stock.

How can I achieve that?

They want two synchronization way. Is that possible to achieve this?

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Pearl